# Windows Task Scheduler hanging when running a batch file that commits to svn

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn, scheduled-tasks

I have the following in a batch file that uses the svn command line client to commit a single file to source control.

```
"%TortoiseSVNPath%\svn.exe" commit %LocalPath%\backup.sql -m "Committing Backup"
```

This works fine when I run it. I'd like to set it up to run every night using Windows Task Scheduler. However, when I do so, it gets stuck at that line. I've discovered that problem occurs because the user the task was created under was not logged into the system. Is there a way to connect to svn, even if they're not logged in?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not because the user wasn't logged in, it's because the user account the scheduled task executes under doesn't have a cached set of credentials that can be accessed by the task.So `svn.exe` is "hanging" while it waits for a non-existent user to enter some credentials.

Explicitly pass the SVN credentials to `svn.exe` with the `--username` and `--password` parameters. You may also find `--no-auth-cache` and `--non-interactive` useful. You should probably have an SVN account dedicated to this sort of activity.

***HOWEVER***

You are probably using Subversion for the wrong purpose in the first place. Subversion **is not a backup system and shouldn't be used as such**. Back up your database properly, using the proper tools.